# How does CNOT gate work?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer

In Quantum Computation there is (among others) a so called [CNOT gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_NOT_gate). Its control input |x> is "driven through", while the other input |y> is converted to some other state, depending on the state of |x>. In principle this is entanglement of |x> and |y>.

Q:I wonder all the time how it can be, that |x> is not affected at all and kept "untouched", although it undergoes "some interaction" with the other sub-system |y>. In the case of any interaction I would expect some probability for system x leaving its original state - otherwise there would be no interaction...so why a |0> of the first subsystem remains and doesn't change occasionally to |1>? This is a bit surprising for me...

Comment: It depends on the physical implementation, do you have any in mind?

Comment: No, do you have an example? Up to now, I had only abstract operations in mind and this is also the outline of my book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a deep misunderstanding: It is not true, that x is driven through the upper path of the CNOT, this is only the case in the base of |1>, |0>.

A more general input

|x>|y> = (|0>+|1>)|0> = |00>+|10>

is a **product state** and yields as output

|00>+|11>

which is and **entangled state** and cannot be written as a product state (|0>+|1>)|y'>

The misleading fact was, that I took the straight line in top of the CNOT as a connector and the dot on it just as a node, as we have it in electrical circuits. This is, of course, a wrong assumption...
A duplicating "branch" of x via the "dot" would violate [non-cloning-theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-cloning_theorem) and is, therefore, physically impossible.

It took some while to realize this.